# normality test and different order of predictors in two-way aov

Tags: r, anova

I have the data shown below:

```
Location=c("lcn","lcn","lcn","etb","lcs","bbs","lcn","lcs","bbs","lcn","lcs","bbs","lcs","lcs","lcn",
"bbs","etb","bbs","etb","etb","lcs","lcn","lcn","bbs","bbs","etb","bbs","etb","bbs","bbs",
"lcs","lcs","lcs","lcs","lcs","lcn","lcs","etb","lcn","lcn","etb","etb","etb","etb","lcn",
"bbs","bbs","lcs","etb","lcs","bbs","bbs","lcs","bbs","lcs","lcn","lcn","lcn","etb","lcn",
"lcs","bbs","etb","etb","etb","bbs","etb","bbs","etb","etb","bbs","lcs")

Treatment=c(rep("control",each=21),rep("foam",each=20),rep("hail",each=17),rep("teda",each=14))

Growth=c( 0.24, -0.05,  0.19,  1.02,  0.84,  0.11,  0.13,  0.08, -0.18, -0.06,
          0.38, 1.04,  0.55, -1.71,  0.24,  0.05,  0.49, -0.41,  0.70,  0.30,
          1.03,  0.14,  0.73,  0.56,  0.56,  0.98,  0.53,  0.27,  0.32,  0.95,
          0.10,  0.55,  1.18,  0.49,  0.58,  0.36,  0.18,  0.30,  1.71,  0.65,
          0.69,  0.68,  0.66,  1.24,  0.47 , 1.28,  0.60,  1.01,  0.76,  1.35,
          1.02,  0.75,  0.40,  0.37,  0.46,  0.47,  0.25,  0.61,  0.63,  0.86,
          0.92,  0.09,  1.66,  0.88,  0.68,  1.02,  1.17,  1.18,  1.71,  1.01,
          0.42,  0.56)


Mang=data.frame(Location,Treatment,Growth)
```

I want to use Two-Way Anova to see the influence of changing `Location` and `Treatment` on `Growth`. Two questions I want to ask:

(1) If some levels of predictors can't pass the normality test (shown below), can I still do the Anova ?

```
> shapiro.test(subset(Mang,Location=="lcn")[,3])$p.value
[1] 0.01317841
> shapiro.test(subset(Mang,Treatment=="control")[,3])$p.value
[1] 0.008312405
```

(2) Why the results are different when the order of predictors is changed in Anova?

```
> test1=aov(Growth~Location+Treatment,data=Mang)
> summary(test1)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   
Location     3  1.713  0.5710   2.708 0.05235 . 
Treatment    3  3.495  1.1650   5.524 0.00193 **
Residuals   65 13.707  0.2109                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ?**?0.001 ?*?0.01 ??0.05 ??0.1 ??1


> test2=aov(Growth~Treatment+Location,data=Mang)
> summary(test2)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Treatment    3  4.402  1.4673   6.958 0.000393 ***
Location     3  0.806  0.2687   1.274 0.290658    
Residuals   65 13.707  0.2109                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ?**?0.001 ?*?0.01 ??0.05 ??0.1 ??1
```

Comment: (1) The data itself doesn't have to be normal, only the residuals: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/anova-assumption-normality-normal-distribution-of-residuals
(2) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13241/the-order-of-variables-in-anova-matters-doesnt-it

Comment: I agree with Artem. Additionally ANOVA assumes your data is homoscedastic ie the residuals have similar variance, a magnitude of 4x is tolerated. Most of the time residual plots will tell you if the model is passable or not. As for the 2nd question check this answer on CV. In your case Type II would probably be the way to go since there is no interaction term.

Comment: I also agree with Artem. However if you make the model you then see: `shapiro.test(mdl$residuals)$p.value  #[1] 0.0003453573`. The biologic process of "growth" is often nonlinear. It's often sigmoid. I don't understand the downvote. The question might not be all about coding and might be more appropriate on CrossValidated.com, but it does have an [MCVE], which puts it well above the typical new SO-user quality.